# alert and mail notification from metricbeat/elasticsearch/kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, redhat, metricbeat

I have installed metricbeat in VM's for collecting the each vm metrics for monitor the cpu,disk,memory, etc utilization. The configuration is set up metricbeat with elasticseatch and kibana .I could see the data flow in kibana dashboard. I want to set the alerts and notify to user for high cpu/memory/disk utilization.
I don't have license and I can't using it.

how to set the alert and notify to user for high cpu/memory/disk/etc utilization.